# Custom Drawable Radio Buttons Android Width and Height Parameters

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-custom-view, android-styles

I have been reading around a few answers on stack overflow and can not seem to get this to work despite trying various suggestions. Maybe there is a "new" way that does?

I am trying to add a custom drawable to two radio buttons in a radio collection:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/orderByRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioStarRating"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
                android:text="@string/filters_star_rating"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline46"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioResponseTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
                android:text="@string/filters_response_time"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline46"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

The Radio buttons

```
`android:button`
```

has been  set with this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxfalse"
            android:width = "30dp"
            android:height = "30dp"/>
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxtrue"
            android:width = "30dp"
            android:height = "30dp"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxfalse"
            android:width = "30dp"
            android:height = "30dp"/>
    </selector>
```

But the outcome is this:

[image]

How can I make the drawable scale correctly? It is as tough the `selector` element doesn't have height and width for the drawable...

Thank you for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Set your selector drawable as background:

```
android:background="@drawable/checkbox"
android:button="@android:color/transparent"
```